# catkin is not creating package

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, create, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> cd ~/catkin_ws/src 
> catkin_create_pkg mypack 
> cd ..
> catkin_make

Everything is ok.

> roscd mypack 
> mypack not found.

why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240354/catkin-is-not-creating-package./) by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscd will not know where to locate your package until you have sourced your setup.bash. After you have compiled, in the catkin_ws directory in the terminal enter 'source devel/setup.bash'.

---

Originally posted by [alexvs](https://answers.ros.org/users/22322/alexvs/) with karma: 91 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oper](https://answers.ros.org/users/27436/oper/) on 2016-07-25**:
Thank u! this was exactly what i was missing